# Using Http response between multiple classes in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, httprequest

```
class XXX implements Runnable
{

String lat,lon,str,taluka_name;
int name;
HttpResponse response;
HttpEntity entity;
InputStream is = null;
Toast s1;
StringBuilder sb=null;
TextView v;
Spinner s;
public String result[];
TextView tv;
LinearLayout ll1;
int i;
ArrayList<Integer> croplist;

public XXX(String t_n,String [] res,LinearLayout ll,TextView tv1)
{
    croplist= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    taluka_name = t_n;
    result = res;
    ll1= ll;
    tv = tv1;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/proagri115.php");
    List<NameValuePair>login=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", taluka_name));
    try 
    {
        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(login);
        request.setEntity(entity);
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try 
    {
        response = httpclient.execute(request);
        entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        System.out.println("Executed the request");
    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line="0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            str=sb.toString();
            Log.e("log_tag", "Success converting result "+sb.toString());
        }
     catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result  "+e.toString());

    System.out.println(str+"I have executed");
    result = str.split(">>");
    System.out.println("length"+result.length);
    for(i=0;i<result.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("\n"+i+"=="+result[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Notified");
   }

   }
   }





public class help extends Activity{
int j;
Intent i;
String s,taluka_name;
EditText edt,edt1,edt2;
Double lat,lon;
Spinner spin;
String [] re;
TextView tv;
Layout lt;
LinearLayout lt1;
XXX runnable;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedinstancestate)
{
    super.onCreate(savedinstancestate);
    setContentView(R.layout.help);
    lt1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll1);
    s =(String)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Rainfall");
    taluka_name =(String)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("location");
    System.out.println(s);
    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Crops for Your Selected Area are");
    lt1.addView(tv);
    try
    {   
         runnable = new XXX(taluka_name,re,lt1,tv);
             Thread threadX = new Thread(runnable);
             System.out.println("till this");
             threadX.start();  
             System.out.println("In Waited");
             try 
             {
            wait(500);
             }
              catch (IllegalMonitorStateException e)
             {
            System.out.println("IllegalMonitorStateException");
             }
             catch (InterruptedException e)
             {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException");
             }
            System.out.println("Out of Waited");
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error again "+e);
    }
    try{
            System.out.println("Final Result will be");
            for(j=0;j<runnable.result.length;j++)
            {
                tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(runnable.result[j]);
                System.out.println(runnable.result[j]);
                lt1.addView(tv);
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

}

}
```

I have main activity and thread XXX. I want to use the result of httprequest in XXX thread to be used in Main activity.But before XXX completes its operation main thread executes and 
I get NullpointerException . How should I use network response in main activity . I have tried "synchronized block" . But It works for methods of single class.
How should I solve this problem?

Comment: No its not about logcat as there is no error.Its only that the main method executes before the thread XXX completes its operation so I cant use http response on thread in main activity.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the main activity with the thread result? Update some control?

Comment: In http response I get some list of agricultural crops from database and the list of crops is shown on display by adding textviews on main activity

Comment: If someone knows the answer please reply fast

Comment: Forget the thread and use an `AsyncTask` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At minimum, you need to use Thread.join to wait for the thread to complete.. But that would block on your UI thread which is really bad. You should really just do this the android way and use an AsyncTask
Read this:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Here is what you should do:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class XXX extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String[]> {

    String lat, lon, str, taluka_name;
    int name;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpEntity entity;
    InputStream is = null;
    Toast s1;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    TextView v;
    Spinner s;
    public String result[];
    TextView tv;
    LinearLayout ll1;
    int i;
    ArrayList<Integer> croplist;

    public XXX(String t_n, String[] res, LinearLayout ll, TextView tv1) {
        croplist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        taluka_name = t_n;
        result = res;
        ll1 = ll;
        tv = tv1;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/proagri115.php");
        List<NameValuePair> login = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", taluka_name));
        try {
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(login);
            request.setEntity(entity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(request);
            entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            System.out.println("Executed the request");
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line = "0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            str = sb.toString();
            Log.e("log_tag", "Success converting result " + sb.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result  " + e.toString());

            System.out.println(str + "I have executed");
            result = str.split(">>");
            System.out.println("length" + result.length);
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("\n" + i + "==" + result[i]);
            }

            System.out.println("Notified");
        }
        return result;
    }



}
```

Then from your activity call:

```
new XXX(taluka_name,re,lt1,tv).execute();
```

Now the tricky thing is you need to get that result back to your UI thread.. The easiest way is to put the AsyncTask within the activity as an inner class, then in onPostExecute of the asyncTask you just call some function from your activity.
If you want the AsyncTask in a seperate file then you need to pass a reference of your class to the constructor of the AsyncTask and then you can call any public method of your activity from the asyncTask. Just remember that you can only call the activities methods in onPostExecute and in onProgressUpdate (do not call UI methods in doInBackground)

Comment: I will update my answer in a minute showing you how to take your code and make it an AsyncTask

Answer (score 4):

You should use a synchronization mechanism whenever two threads need to cooperate and exchange information.

You can use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to post an action back to the UI thread when the HTTP request completes in the background thread or better yet perform the background work in [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Here is a general example:

```
private class AsyncTaskExample extends AsyncTask<Param, Progress, Result> {
    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(Param... params) {
         // Performs some computation in a background thread.
         // Use publishProgress() to publish progress updates which
         // will take place in the UI thread in onProgressUpdate().
         return ...;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress... progress) {
        // Update progress information. Run in the UI thread.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
        // Update on completion. Run in the UI thread.
    }
}
```

Note that `AsyncTask` is a generic class and requires three parameters: `Param` for input data to the background computation, `Result` for the result of the computation and `Progress` to represent progress update information.

Note also that `doInBackground()` is the only abstract method in `AsyncTask`, so at minimum you must override just this one method. In most cases, you will find `onPostExecute()` and `onProgressUpdate()` very useful as well. For more overridable methods and details see [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Once you have defined a task class you can launch the computation it represents in the background by in the following way:

```
new AsyncTaskExample().execute(param1, param2, ...);
```

Passing parameters (of type `Param`) to `execute()`. Note that this must be done in the UI thread.